How to find title and data categories for archived and deleted knowledge articles?
I'm using the Salesforce REST API to retrieve archived and deleted knowledge articles. However, I'm not able to find the title and data categories of these articles.
APIS:
Archived:
/services/data/v60.0/query?q=SELECT+id,KnowledgeArticleId,ArticleNumber,Title,PublishStatus,LastModifiedDate+FROM+Knowledge__kav+WHERE+PublishStatus='Archived'+AND+LastModifiedDate+>+xxx

This retrieves title but not data categories.
Deleted:
/services/data/v60.0/queryAll?q=SELECT+Id,isDeleted,ArticleNumber,SystemModstamp+FROM+KnowledgeArticle+WHERE+isDeleted+=+TRUE+AND+SystemModstamp+>+xxx

This retrieves neither the title nor data categories
Can someone help me with above details please?
